# lock ES File Explorer or similar options

Tags: applications

I want to lock ES file explorer, so that it can be opened after I put a password or pattern lock.

Is it possible in ES file explorer?
Is there any other file explorer that provides similar functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There are many apps on the market that allows you to password-/PIN-/pattern- protect other apps, see: https://market.android.com/search?q=app+lock